# Select file based on number of lines and manipulate the result

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, wc

I have a large number of files, all with the same format.

```
line 1: Gene ID
line 2: chromosomal position
line 3 - x: names of genetic variants)
```

I want to select only files containing at least 5 variants (i.e. files that have at least 10 lines in total). If a file has at least 5 variants I want to write the content minus the first two rows to a new file.
Below I provide two example input files, `foo1` and `foo2`.

foo1:

```
echo {885743,4:139381:3783883,rs93487,rs82727,rs111} | tr " " "\n" > foo1
```

foo2:

```
echo {10432,1:3747548:2192993,rs10204,rs262222,rs436363,rs3636,rs9878,rs11856} | tr " " "\n" > foo2
```

Desired output file (in this case only 1 file, in reality there will be multiple separate output files): `foo2.checked`, looking like:

```
rs10204
rs262222
rs436363
rs3636
rs9878
rs11856
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 # for each file in the current directory you can refine the ls command to match 
 # only the files you want. or if in a script file pass in the file list 
 for file in *
 do
    # if the file has more than 10 lines.
    if (( $(<"${file}" wc -l) > 10 )); then
       # print line 3 to end of file and pipe it to a file with the same
       # name as the input file with the added .checked at the end.
       sed -n '3,$p' -- "${file}" > "${file}.checked"
    fi
 done
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced `ls -1` by `fnames.txt` containing a list of filenames, to prevent the command from being executed on other (non relevant) files in the directory.

Comment: Archemar's solution was pretty close too. :) Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

assuming no file with funny char in their name

```
 for file in *
 do
    line=$(wc -l < "$file' )
    if [ $line -ge 10 ]
    then
       tail -n +3 <"$file" > "${file}.checked"
    fi
 done
```

this basically count line in every file, then if over 10, print all lines, starting at the third.